# How to get data from a specific class in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

HTML code

```js
$(".values").click(function(){
  $(".values").each(function(){
    var value = $(this).data('value');
    alert(value);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<p class="values" data-value="1">Value 1</p>
<p class="values" data-value="2">Value 2</p>
<p class="values" data-value="3">Value 3</p>
<p class="values" data-value="4">Value 4</p>
<p class="values" data-value="5">Value 5</p>
```

The problem is when i click in a specific **p** tag he alerts all the p tags with the data values, and i need that the click event trigger one alert with the specific data value.

Comment: Don't use `alert`, use `console.log` to see what's happening. That said, you wrote code that applies to all `p` elements due to that `each`. That's how jQuery chaining works, so this is a case of "it might be time to read up on using jQuery a little again" because that's part of the fundamentals for any code using jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the `.each` loop.

```js
$(".values").click(function(){
    var value = $(this).data('value');
    alert(value);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<p class="values" data-value="1">Value 1</p>
<p class="values" data-value="2">Value 2</p>
<p class="values" data-value="3">Value 3</p>
<p class="values" data-value="4">Value 4</p>
<p class="values" data-value="5">Value 5</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are using jQuery selection you don't need to loop to each selected item to attach event handler. jQuery will handle that internaly you will just have to use `$(this)` to target the item which is clicked at a given time

```js
$('.values').click(function(){
    console.log($(this).data('value'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="values" data-value="1">Value 1</p>
<p class="values" data-value="2">Value 2</p>
<p class="values" data-value="3">Value 3</p>
<p class="values" data-value="4">Value 4</p>
<p class="values" data-value="5">Value 5</p>
```